# Is there a logical way to do this condition?

Tags: php, logic

I was curious, is there a way to compress this condition with logic :

```
if($var1 == 'foo' || $var2 == 'foo' OR $var3 == 'foo')
```

to something more compact like:

```
if(($var1 ||$var2 || $var3) == 'foo')
```

I think php  don't allow it, but I'm curipous to know if there is a "logic trick" to do something more or less like that (even if the condition is finally longer than the original) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out a few possibilities, I think that [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is your best option. [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915116/) is one of those and the original / first answer given; this is just a supplement to.

You could do it this way and setup an array beforehand, if that is what you're looking to do, for any other added variables.

```
$var1 =  "foo"; // yep
$var2 =  "foo2"; // nope
$var3 =  "foo3"; // nope
$var4 =  "foo"; // yep

$vars = array("$var1","$var2","$var3","$var4");
if (in_array("foo", $vars)) //Founds a match !
{
    echo "Yep";
}

else
{
    echo "Nope";
}
```

Comment: In deed, I find that compiling the array before the condition is better, I accept this one, But Jhon would consider his one is accepted to

Comment: @CarlierRobin You can use either/or. I was just happy to have helped out. John and I sometimes work together on helping to solve problems; however John is much more experienced than I am and I value that very much; *cheers*.

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` can shorten this up a bit:

```
if (in_array('foo', array($var1, $var2, $var3))) {

}
```

Comment: +1 Would a ternary operator work also, in OP's case?

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll wait a bit see other ideas, but this one is pretty good

Comment: I can't think of a way to use it without it becoming convoluted. At least not more so than this.

Comment: As said, I'm only interessed by the logic, so I'm open even if this is highly convoluted. But obviously shorter is better ;)

Comment: @CarlierRobin Ternaries work something like this `$var = isset($_POST['option']) ? 1 : 0;` - You can find examples in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

```
if (($var1 == $var2) && ($var2 == $var3)) {
    // hurrah they're the same
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of comparing the vars beetween them, but this way could be really long if there is a lot of vars to compare, with 10 var it could be much longer.

Comment: Oh man yeah imagine if there were like 50! Think it's fine for just a few though.